# Program that solves a simple math equation

Tags: java, math, equation, square-root

I'm having trouble understanding the syntax of Java and how to use Java to solve math equations. Below is just an example of a simple equation. I want the program to simply be able to output the result of the calculation. If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it!

```
2.6^22 + 3.9^15
```

Comment: Use `Math.pow(number, exponent)`... so like, `Math.pow(2.6, 22)`

Comment: So many answers that are all correct. Do I upvote all of them or none of them? I feel so conflicted...

Comment: Upvote all of them :)

Comment: What if I added a square root to the original equation?

Comment: @User2499376 then following will be your answer when you have square root double ans=Math.pow((Math.pow(2.6,22)+Math.pow(3.9,15)),0.5);

Comment: Upvote all answers, downvote the question and vote to close!

Answer (score 4):

See also the [`ScriptEngine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html).

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import javax.swing.*;

class EvaluateString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5,5));
                final JTextField input = new JTextField(
                        "Math.pow(2.6,22)+ Math.pow(3.9,15)",19);
                final JTextField output = new JTextField(15);
                output.setEditable(false);

                gui.add(input, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                gui.add(output, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

                // obtain a reference to the JS engine
                final ScriptEngine engine = new 
                        ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("js");
                ActionListener calculate = new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        try {
                            String s = ((Double)engine.eval(input.getText())).toString();
                            output.setText(s);
                        } catch (ScriptException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                input.addActionListener(calculate);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
        Double sum=Math.pow(2.6, 22) + Math.pow(3.9,15);
        System.out.println("sum-->"+sum);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
public class Equ {
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      System.out.println(Math.pow(2.6, 22) + Math.pow(3.9,15));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use the Math class, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html),.
in your case you can do:

```
Double result = Math.pow(2.6,22) + Math.pow(3.9, 15);
```

that's it,.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Math library.

```
 Math.pow(2.6,22) + Math.pow(3.9,15);
```

This will return a `double`

The first argument of `pow` function is the base and the second argument is the power.